# jQuery convert text from textbox to anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html

I am needing to put in a "secret" way of putting HTML into a textarea. Currently, I have a textarea and when a submit button is clicked, it posts the value to MySQL via ajax/php.

Instead of allowing HTML to be put into the textarea box (for security reasons), I am wanting a way to put something like `#http://www.example.com/file.php#` . Then on submit, it would convert anything inside the # symbol to an anchor tag

This - 
`#http://www.example.com/file.php#`

Would turn into this - `<a href='http://www.example.com/file.php'>www.example.com</a>`

Comment: Thanks for all the downvotes... No explanation why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var A= $("p").html().replace("#","").replace("#","");
$("body").append( $("<a/>",{href:A,html:A.match(/(www?\w*\.)\w+\.\w+/g)}))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>#http://www.example.com/file.php#</p>
```